# Change content of span class with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, getelementsbyclassname

I need to change the content of spans with a class name using JavaScript. I prefer JavaScript over jQuery because this is a basic site and isn't loading a jQuery file, and I'd rather not add on the file just for this one thing. Here is what I've tried:

HTML:

```
blah blah blah <span class="new"></span> blah blah blah
```

JavaScript in external JavaScript file:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('.new')[0].innerHTML = 'new text here';
```

Hoping it would show up as:
blah blah blah new text here blah blah blah

Did a search but only found ElementID solutions.

Comment: `'.new'` without dot, so `document.getElementsByClassName('new')[0].innerHTML`

Comment: I removed the dot but it's still not working. I should have mentioned I tried that as well. Would the fact that I have my external js file loaded just before the </body> tag make a difference? Or the [0] maybe? Note: All the other scripts on the js file work fine, so it's loading.

Comment: According to [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4castle/2rz96p6q/) it works fine. Can you provide some code that reproduces your issue?

Comment: thanks for creating the fiddle, helped a lot to see it worked. still wasn't working for me so there's something weird with the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried the code on a different site on the same host and still didn't work. I modified the code based on an elementID code I found on a similar site within their host and this worked:

```
var newText = document.getElementsByClassName('new')[0];
newText.innerHTML = 'new text here';
```

No idea why, but this worked. Thanks for the responses!

Comment: I think I know why. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28163033/when-is-nodelist-live-and-when-is-it-static). If you want the most stable & predictable solution, use the `onload` event.

Answer (score 3):

You are almost there, Just remove the `.` from `class name`. 
The reason is, when you call the `getElementsByClassName` method. It Searches the whole Document for class names only.So you don't need to put `.` before the class name.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('new')[0].innerHTML = 'new text here';
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, didn't realize that.

Comment: Glad it helps. @midknyte

Answer (score 1):

Don't put a period before new.

`document.getElementsByClassName('new')[0].innerHTML = 'new text here';`

Comment: Added a new comment above. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the dot `.` from `'.new'`. It is implied since the function only looks for classes.

**Update**: According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8717401/is-the-onload-necessary-when-the-code-is-at-the-bottom), yes, it's possible that putting your JavaScript code at the bottom still isn't always enough to guarantee the DOM is fully loaded. You will have to do the replacement after `document.onload`.

```
document.onload = function() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('.new')[0].innerHTML = 'new text here';
}
```

Comment: Added a new comment above. Thanks.

Comment: I've updated my answer to address your problem.

Comment: Thanks for that. Not sure why but using a variable worked.

Answer (score -1):

As it has been stated already, remove the dot ('.') from your selector. 
If you would like to select classes that way, I'd recommend using document.querySelector or document.querySelectorAll :)

Comment: That would be a poor decision. The `querySelector` functions are much slower & aren't needed here.

Comment: Added a new comment above. Thanks.